# how to call function from another class in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

here is my code:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "secd.h"



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_triggered()
{
    secD secdialog;
    secdialog.setModal(true);
    secdialog.exec();

}


void function1()  //this function I need to call from secd.cpp
{
//do something   
}
```

secd.cpp:

```
#include "secd.h"
#include "ui_secd.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "mainwindow.h"


secD::secD(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::secD)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

secD::~secD()
{
    delete ui;
}

void secD::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("About");
    msgBox.exec();
    function1();  //how to call this function?
}
```

So I need to call from secd.cpp function1() which is in mainwindow.cpp
how can I do it?  maybe with connect and signals and slots? but i don't understand that documentation.

Comment: You made `function1()` to be a free function and not a class member of your MainWindow. While you could use a lambda to call it  using signals and slots you may just want to call it directly.

Comment: wow how easy! thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype of function should be declared for source file directly or in a header:

```
#include "secd.h"
#include "ui_secd.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "mainwindow.h"

void function1();    // <---------------------------

secD::secD(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::secD)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

secD::~secD()
{
    delete ui;
}

void secD::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("About");
    msgBox.exec();
    function1();  //how to call this function?
}
```